# How to use $_product on Magento Catalog template pages

Tags: magento2, magento-catalog

I have overridden the Magento catalog phtml file in our store's custom template to display a link to a custom instructional page that we created.

[image]

Problem is, I only want this link to display on *certain* product pages.

I've noticed that on this page we have access to the variable `$_product` through the call to

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

I've tried logging this object using print_r, etc. but nothing seems to work. How can I see the shape of this object so that I can figure out how to locate something like: `$_product->category`

Any advice on a better procedure to get this kind of functionality into the catalog?

Comment: have you created custom block also?

Comment: @Abdul curious if that's a better way to go, when would you want to create a custom block for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the data of a product you can use following.

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_product->getData());
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

To get name of product you can use following for example

```
$_product->getName();
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything though, just an empty code area from the <pre></pre> tags -- does this mean that there is no product data?

Comment: Please check get_class($_product);  and let me know what output you get.

Comment: @DanielThompson I have updated my answer. Please try with it.

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor

Comment: that is the correct class you are getting. Please try with the updated answer.

Comment: `print_r($_product->getData());` crashes the page with 500 error, even though it appears to be returning an array type...

Comment: Ok that means there is data. Can you print $_product->getName();

Comment: ahhh yes thank you that's what I needed! Is there a place the other attributes are documented?

Comment: Very Good answer  :)

Comment: @DanielThompson You get product object now whichever attribute you want you can use by either directly as we get name or by getting `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Your_Attribute_Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`